# prevent custom iterator from getting nullptr

Tags: c++

I wrote a PriorityQueue class and an iterator class for it. But I don't understand why these
line compile?

```
PriorityQueue<int,int> pq;
   auto z =pq.begin();
   z=nullptr;
```

I mean, The iterator isn't a pointer(It has a pointer in it,but there is no conversion between them).How can I prevent this from hapenning?

EDIT: The begin decleration:

```
const iterator begin() const;
```

Comment: If there's no conversion from pointer type to your iterator then `z=nullptr` shouldn't compile anyway.

Comment: Show the declaration of your `begin()` function, and the iterator type it returns.

Comment: There isn't a conversion.

Comment: The compiler thinks there is.  Show that part of the code and we'll tell you if you're right.  (Really, where you're wrong, since the compiler is almost always right)

Comment: Consider stepping into the line `z=nullptr` with a debugger to see what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks for the `begin()` declaration, but we still need the definition of `iterator`.

Comment: (BTW: `begin() const` should usually return a `const_iterator`... `const iterator` is not the same thing)

Comment: If I have an contructor for the Iterator like this :Iterator(Node<Priority,T>* node) : node(node) {} that gets only one parameter, is it like conversion?

Comment: @user3706035: Yes, that creates a conversion unless it is marked with the `explicit` keyword.

Comment: so I am suppose to add a parameter for nothing like an int so it won't do it? Is it the right way of fixing it?

Comment: @user3706035: Single-argument constructors should be marked `explicit` if you don't want them to enable implicit conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your single argument constructor

```
iterator::iterator(Node<Priority,T>* node) : node(node) {}
```

establishes a user-defined conversion from a pointer type `Node<Priority,T>*` to `iterator`.  Since `nullptr_t` implicitly converts to any pointer type, that gives you a conversion from `nullptr` to your `iterator` type.  The line `z = nullptr;` in your example then implicitly converts `nullptr` to the iterator type, before calling the automatically-generated move- or copy-assignment operator.

Fix: Add the `explicit` keyword to your constructor.

```
explicit iterator(Node<Priority,T>* node) : node(node) {}
```

---

Rule from the Standard, section 12.3.1:

> A constructor declared without the *function-specifier* `explicit` speciﬁes a conversion from the types of its parameters to the type of its class.  Such a constructor is called a *converting constructor*.
>
> An  explicit  constructor  constructs  objects  just  like  non-explicit  constructors,  but  does  so  only  where  the direct-initialization  syntax  (8.5)  or  where  casts  (5.2.9,  5.4)  are  explicitly  used.  A default  constructor may be an explicit constructor;  such a constructor will be used to perform default-initialization or value-initialization (8.5).